# Dynamic DataTable - PrimeFaces / Java

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I am developing a system using PrimeFaces and want to generate "dynamic" in the form (ajax) depending on options of chosen tables.

Example:

__ DataTable1
***X* DataTable2**
__ DataTable3
   .
   .
   .
*_* DataTable???

__ Line1
__ Line2
***X* Line3**
   .
   .
   .
*_* Line???

Result:

```
<p:dataTable>
    <f:facet name="header"> DataTable2 </f:facet>
    <p:columnGroup type="header">
    <p:row>
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="Line3" />
        </p:column>
     </p:row>
</p:dataTable>
```

But what if, after this table is ready, I select DataTable1 and Line2? I want a second table with the selected data to be shown on the screen.

Does anyone know how I can fix this? (Can I have 1 or X tables)

Trying to explain better what I need .

For each click on the button add , need to create a new table on the screen .

Answer (score 0):

Though your question is still not that clear and I would have been able to help you better if you have provided your code.However from what I have understood I think,what you need to use is something similar to this:-

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml

First of all you need to use a Data Table where you can select rows.You can implement it by using the  `selectionMode="single"` inside your `datatable` tag.
Next you must be calling a bean to this rowselect ajax event via something like this

```
<p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{yourBean.selectedmethod}" update=":form1:table" />
```

Now you must be showing the data table from the selectedmethod bean using FacesContext or you can even use JavaScript to do so.